# Solar panel locaiton with plex-earth and virtocad

Tags: cad, photovoltaics, solar

I need to use Plex-Earth and VirtoCad to solve a solar panel positioning problem. I am on BricsCad.

I have a kml for a boundary area.

How can I, using these softwares, get the following groudn mount build: Trackers will have to be installed on the ground, only in locations with a maximum inclination of 10 degrees to the south and -5 degrees to the north. Trackers 7 metres apart.

With plex-earth slope and direction I am having trouble understanding what maximum inclination 10º south and -5 degrees north mean